# Page results from query coming back in random order

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j-4

A quick question on sort order using spring-data-neo4j

I'm using the following query to get a 'category path'.

```
@Query("MATCH (c1:Category {sceneId: {categoryId}})-[r:PARENT*]->(c2:Category) RETURN c1, r, c2")
    Page<Category> getCategoryPath(@Param("categoryId") String categoryId, Pageable pageable);
```

In our system, categories are structured as a tree, and a single category path is the path from a leaf category to the root category.

For example, the following is a category path:

> (c1:Category)<-[:PARENT]-(c2:Category)<-[:PARENT]-(c3:Category)

The issue I am having with this is that the Categories are returned in the Page object out of order. I want the categories in order of leaf to parent, or parent to leaf (doesn't matter which), not random order.

Any tips?

Comment: Technically, having a `Pageable` in your method parameters automatically adds an `ORDER BY` clause to the query.

Comment: So, you can have an order on c1 properties or c2 properties but not both.
Maybe representing the hierarchy in your domain model (nested categories in categories) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without an `ORDER BY`, there's no guarantee about page order. Not sure if there's a good way for you to add an order by for your use case. You may want a custom query result here but I can't guarantee that it'll fix your use case till we play around with this data some more